# Tooltip doesn't show up again

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, tooltip

I have a Mac app that exclusively live on the menu bar. It has a progress bar and a label. The label shows the percentage of the progress of the task that's being carried out. I want to show more info when the user hovers the mouse pointer over the progress indicator.

[image]

When I set the tooltip initially and hover over, it displays without an issue.

But if I head over somewhere and open the menu app again and hover over again, the tooltip doesn't come up. I can't figure out why. Here's my code.

[image]

**ProgressMenuController.swift**

```
import Cocoa

class ProgressMenuController: NSObject {

    @IBOutlet weak var menu: NSMenu!
    @IBOutlet weak var progressView: ProgressView!

    let menuItem = NSStatusBar.systemStatusBar().statusItemWithLength(NSVariableStatusItemLength)

    var progressMenuItem: NSMenuItem!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        menuItem.menu = menu
        menuItem.image = NSImage(named: "icon")

        progressMenuItem = menu.itemWithTitle("Progress")
        progressMenuItem.view = progressView

        progressView.update(42)
    }

    @IBAction func quitClicked(sender: NSMenuItem) {
        NSApplication.sharedApplication().terminate(self)
    }
}
```

**ProgressView.swift**

```
import Cocoa

class ProgressView: NSView {

    @IBOutlet weak var progressIndicator: NSProgressIndicator!
    @IBOutlet weak var progressPercentageLabel: NSTextField!

    func update(value: Double) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.progressIndicator.doubleValue = value
            self.progressIndicator.toolTip = "3 out of 5 files has been copied"
            self.progressPercentageLabel.stringValue = "\(value)%"
        }
    }
}
```

This is a demo app similar to my actual app. So the `update()` function is called only once and the values are hardcoded. But in my actual app, the progress is tracked periodically and the `update()` function gets called with it to update the values. The label's percentage value and the progress indicator's value get updated without a problem. The issue is only with the tooltip.

Is this expected behavior or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same problem, and realized the issue was that only the currently focused window will display tool-tips, but after my app lost focus, it would never get it back. Focus usually transfers automatically when the user clicks on your window, but it isn't automatic for menu bar apps. Using NSApp.activate, you can regain focus onto your app:

```
 override func viewWillAppear() {
    super.viewWillAppear()
    NSApp.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[sanche's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47084053/1091063) worked for me as well, but I ended up moving the tool tips to my `NSMenuItem`s instead so I wouldn't have to steal focus from the foreground app. `NSMenuItem`'s tool tips seem to be handled as a special case so the app doesn't need to be focused.

This solution would make the tool tip apply to everything in the menu item and appear next to the menu rather than over it, but it looks like that might not be a problem in your case.